# backbone.js and sqlite - storing json object and de-serializing it properly

Tags: javascript, json, sqlite, backbone.js

Here is my code:

```
var toJson = {};
var jsStr = JSON.stringify(picturesExist);
toJSON = JSON.parse(jsStr);
for (var t in toJSON) {
    alert(toJSON[t]);
}
```

As far as I am aware, you cannot store json objects in a SQL lite database, you have to store it in a TEXT field. To do this, you have to jsonStringify the object and pass it into the model you have defined.

The problem is, after you get the json object back as a string/array - it looks like this:

```
["xxx.jpg","xxx.jpg","xxx.jpg"]
```

And then I turn it into a json object:

```
var toJson = {};
var jsStr = JSON.stringify(picturesExist);
toJSON = JSON.parse(jsStr);
```

after applying the for in loop , it basically prints out all the characters line by line, leading me to believe that it thinks the object is a string.

What's the best way to deserialize it?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you stringifying and then parsing?  You'll want to stringify before going into the database and parse as it comes out, but never both.  And afterwards don't do a `for in` but do a `.forEach` or for loop.

Comment: I get a parsing error if I try to parse it directly

Comment: Is `picturesExist` a string of JSON or an array?

Comment: thanks caleb, seems to be working now - for some odd reason it didnt work before, when I tried that route.

Comment: You have mistake in name of variable `toJSON`: `var toJson = {}; toJSON = JSON.parse(jsStr);`. `toJson` and `toJSON` two different variables